# How to synchronize access to a database, one thread at a time

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework-6, locking

I have developed a Windows Service in C# that receives events from an external hardware. For each received event, a SQLite database creates a record and save it.

The problem is that from time to time, a DBLock error occurs, so I need to control that only one thread can write to the database at a time.

I have created this class variable that is instantiated in Service OnStart method:

```
private DataWare.monitorEntities _db;
```

Then, in the event, I have:

```
void driver_Transaccion(object sender, AttendanceReader.MarcacionEventArgs e)
{
      lock (_db)
      {
          /* Code that creates a record a does some other actions */
          /* ......... */
          _db.SaveChanges();
      }
}
```

The problem is that I continue receiving the DBLock exception, so, it seems the instruction lock (_db) is not taken into account.

Any help, please?

Comment: Instead of allowing multiple threads to write to the database, implement a queue and have threads add records to the queue. Then have the database pull records from the queue.

Answer (score 0):

Are you disposing your connection after usage?

```
lock (_lockObj)
{
    using (MyEntities context = new MyEntities)
    {
        // do stuff
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: no... I am using a global connection that is opened in OnStart method of the Windows Service. I have "_db.Dispose();" in OnStop method. By using only one variable and connection I was planning to use lock(_db) to control access to the database. I had that "using" before, but I also had synchronization problems.

Comment: I will try to use "using" statement again and implement the use of Mutex, because I need to synchronize database access from different applications writing to the same database.